# Split comma separated values into individual rows

Tags: mysql

I want to create separate rows which will contain one word in each cell. These words are currently stored in several cells in one column.

Below is the format that I have

> A
>   play, games, online, free, fun
>   fun, play, arcade, online
>   racing, funny, play

To be converted into below

> B
>   play
>   games
>   online
>   free
>   fun
>   arcade
>   racing
>   funny

Please note, if one row is already created for one word it should not be repeated.

Comment: Define "cell", since databases don't have cells. Is this in a spreadsheet?

Comment: which prog. lang. you are you using?

Comment: Mysql can't do this (but postgres at least can)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928325/split-keywords-for-post-php-mysql/3929161#3929161

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is typically better done in something other than SQL, like java.

Pseudo code could be:

```
List<String> names = jdbcTemplate.query("select A from your_table", new RowMapper() {
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        return resultSet.getString(1);
    }
});

for (String name : names) {
    String[] strings = name.split("[\\w,]");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String string = strings[i];
        jdbcTemplate.update("insert ignore into new_table (B) values (?)", string);
    }

}
```