# Select using join tables and array in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi there I have 2 tables

```
|id|musicname|url|image|type
```

and the second table

```
|id|user|songslist|
```

inside songsids theres an array like this
1,3,5,6,8 etc ...

What Im aiming to do is select * from table1 and echo out the table1 as in an array but instead of tables two array , the actual row of table1.

So basically To take out each row that contains the id in songslist and put them all into a php array.

I have learned a lot about PHP arrays , but I'm not that good with mysql , Any Idea of how can I do that ?

EDIT

```
$selectmusiclist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music");
$songslist = array();
while ($songs = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectmusiclist)){
 $songslist[] = $songs;
}
```

and then table 2 select:

```
 $username="user1";
 $selectuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersmusic where user=$username");
 $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectuser);
 $songslist = $user['songslist'];
```

NOW I need to tell the array $songslist[] to output only the songs with id $songslist contained ids

Comment: What is the current code you are selecting and outputting with?

Comment: `$selectmusiclist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music"); $songslist = array(); 
while ($songs = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectmusiclist)){$songslist[] = $songs; }`

of course that only outputs table 1 but I need it to interact with table 2
I also use the `foreach` for outputting it separately

Comment: Please update your question with code so it is easier to read. Are you asking how to get all data from the two tables in one query or how to get just the ids?

Comment: @chris85 I have edited the question , I hope it helps !

Comment: So `songslist` of `usersmusic` is the `id` from `music`?

Comment: @chris85 Yes It is right, I have updated the question with all the possible details now !

Comment: So, just to be clear, the songslist column of the usersmusic table contains a comma separated string of song ids, that correspond to ids in the music table?

Comment: ^if that is right answer below won't work; I presume each row is its own record.

Comment: Yes thats right , its comma separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think running a join like this will give you the results you are after.

```
SELECT * FROM usersmusic as um
join music as m
on um.songslist = m.id
where user = '$username'
```

If `$username` is not a static value make sure you escape it; don't want to get SQL injected in the future.

Also note the `mysql_` driver is now deprecated you should consider updating to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thankyou , I hope this works , Im going to test it now , thankyou !

Comment: yes you are right I did accept right away out of excitement, yes there was needed USE of ` and ' in your answer , but this is exactly what Ive been looking for! It does select exactly how I needed it to , but it only selects 1 row, usually 1st one of the songslist , If I could figure that out too it would be great!

Comment: Wait, `songslist` is a comma separated list..and this works?

Comment: I used the while loop! I even used straight in phpmyadmin this command `SELECT * FROM usersmusic as um join music as m on um.songslist = m.id where user = 'user1'`

Comment: Yes it does work!!! But As I said , it only displaying 1 result whatever is the first value in `songslist`

Comment: If it is comma separated then `um.songslist`  will not equal `m.id`...or maybe in one example if only one song/id is listed? Is that what you are getting?

Comment: Yes I'm getting 1 song with 1 id that is what Im trying to say, it only gives 1 answer

Comment: Yes because `1,2,3` will not equal a single id. You should normalize the data. 1 row per song.

Comment: So is there a solution?

Comment: Separate the data into their own records or their might be some hacky solution to get it work but in the future you will continue to run into issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Well at least your answer Was close to a solution, I might just use it separating the songslist into songs or something like that

Comment: You could try out this answer as well for normalizing the data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648115/split-comma-separated-values-into-individual-rows.

Comment: I was thinking to do WHERE id = phparray or something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476146/mysql-php-select-where-id-array , Ill see how it goes , Ill let you know once I found what has worked :)