# Removing the entries in a comma separated field based on the data of another table

Tags: mysql, join

First off I am using MySQL 5.0.96. (always forget to mention that)

I have two tables(`TMP_VIN_STOCK` and `newvehicles`)  I load `TMP_VIN_STOCK` with our current inventory of vehicles daily.

`newvehicles` is our currently listed vehicles on our website table.

I want to find results in `newvehicles` that are NOT in `TMP_VIN_STOCK`. (So I can remove them from website because we sold them)

`TMP_VIN_STOCK.name` and `newvehicles.stocknum` are each tables stock number column.

`TMP_VIN_STOCK.name` has only **single** values of a stock number
`newvehicles.stocknum`  can have **multiple** values separated by commas in it. (Same exact vehicle just multiple stock numbers)

Example:

### TMP_VIN_STOCK table

```
- K12049
- S12040
- T12020
```

### newvehicles table

```
- S12018, S12039, S12040
- Y13068, Y13093
- T12020
```

How can I find out what stock numbers are not in TMP_VIN_STOCK but are in newvehicles?

Comment: It is the commas that are throwing me off!

Comment: this is a very bad database design, do you want it fixed or you want to stick with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem beautifully demonstrates why tables in relational databases should be normalized.

If you want to keep this design then you have to do something like this:

```
loop over the newvehicles rows:
    loop over the items in the comma separated field
        check if the item does not exist in TMP_VIN_STOCK
```

Not to mention that mysql does not have a function to split a comma separated list and
let alone the pain you should go through to remove the ones you find from the comma separated list.

You should definitely redesign your database. Have a table for vehicle data and another one for stock data and link them with foreign keys. That way you don't have to go through all this pain. You can retrieve the data you want with a simple query.

Also if an entry is not in the stock, its data should not be deleted but the count should be zero or it should be flagged as out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928325/split-keywords-for-post-php-mysql/3929161#3929161) has some details that would let you split the values in newvehicles table and let you populate a (temp) table with the results then a `not exists` or `not in` query would give the results you need.

Alternatively you could keep the previous days load of TMP_VIN_STOCK (maybe add a date field into the table - then you could compare what you loaded today with what you loaded yesterday