# select duplicated record and count record from comma separated in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need a query to select duplicate records and count the total duplicate records,

```
Posted Records


PostID | Location

  1    | Delhi,Mumbai,Patna
  2    | Mumbai,Noida
  3    | Delhi
  4    | Mumbai,Noida
```

I would like this result

```
  Location  | Total
  Delhi     | 2
  Mumbai    | 3
  Patna     | 1
  Noida     | 2
```

Comment: That would be very easy, if you had a junction table instead of comma separated values. Can you change the database design? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and read the list in the accepted answer, I cite Bill Karwin: **"Hard to count elements in the list, or do other aggregate queries"**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928325/split-keywords-for-post-php-mysql/3929161 could be of help too.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is you should normalize your structure get rid of comma separated values and use another table to relate your locations with your posts table  see [**Database normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),for you current structure what you can do is get all locations from your table and insert them into new table then use aggregate function on your new table

```
CREATE TABLE locaions (cities CHAR(255)) ;

SET @S1 = CONCAT(
  "INSERT INTO locaions (cities) VALUES ('",
  REPLACE(
    (SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(`Location`) AS DATA 
    FROM
      `posts`),
    ",",
    "'),('"
  ),
  "');"
) ;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1 ;

EXECUTE stmt1 ;
```

This will insert all the locations with repeated data in location table and then use below query to get your desired count

```
SELECT cities,count(*) 
FROM locaions 
group by cities
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c09c7/1)