# sql join tables where 1 column has comma

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I get all usernames when I search "new1" .For eg: I should get A and B as userids 1,2 in tblC is 1,2 for row1 which has new1.What query should I use to get the above result?
I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab8e/2

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
user varchar(255),
 category int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
username varchar(255),
 userid int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
nname varchar(255),
 userids varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (user, category ) VALUES
('1', '1'),
('1', '2'),
('1', '3'),
('1', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('3', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('2', '1');


INSERT INTO tblB (userid, username ) VALUES
('1', 'A'),
('2', 'B'),
('3', 'C'),
('4', 'D'),
('5', 'E');


INSERT INTO tblC (id, nname,userids ) VALUES
('1', 'new1','1,2'),
('2', 'new2','1,3'),
('3', 'new3','1,4'),
('4', 'new4','3,2'),
('5', 'new5','5,2');
```

Query so far:

```
select * where nname="new1" from  tblC
CROSS JOIN tblB
ON tblB.userid=(SELECT userids FROM substr(tblC.userids,','))
```

Comment: You need to read on TABLE NORMALIZATION

Comment: @Prix But how Can I match this way? Is it possible ?

Comment: Should be possible to use `ON (FIND_IN_SET(tblB.userid, tblC.userids) > 0)` It would be _way better_ to normalize this though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [split keywords for post php mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928325/split-keywords-for-post-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really look at [**Database normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and first normalize your structure by adding a junction table and holds a relation from tablec  each relation stored in tablec will be stored in new junction table but not as comma separated list each row will hold id of c and one user id per row ,if you can't alter your schema you can use `find_in_set` to find values in set

```
select *  
from  tblC c
JOIN tblB b
ON (find_in_set(b.userid,c.userids) > 0)
where c.nname="new1"
```

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab8e/3)

---

**Edit for normalize schema**

I have removed `userids` column from your `tblC` and instead i have created a new junction table as `tblC_user` with 2 columns `c_id` this will related to the id column of  `tblC` and second one `userid` to store user relations users for `tblC` see sample schema for  `tblC`

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
nname varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tblC (id, nname) VALUES
('1', 'new1'),
('2', 'new2'),
('3', 'new3'),
('4', 'new4'),
('5', 'new5');
```

And here is your junction table as `tblC_user`

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC_user
(
 c_id int,
 userid int
);

INSERT INTO tblC_user (c_id,userid) VALUES
('1','1'),
('1','2'),
('2','1'),
('2','3'),
('3','1'),
('3','4'),
('4','3'),
('4','2'),
('5','5'),
('5','2');
```

In above  if you notice i haven't stored any comma separated relations each relation of user for  `tblC` is stored in new row ,for you concerned result set i have used junction table in join also new query will be like below

```
select *  
from  tblC c
join tblC_user cu on(c.id = cu.c_id)
join tblB b on (b.userid = cu.userid)
where c.nname="new1"
```

[**Demo 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be372)

Now above query can can be optimized by using indexes you can maintain cascading relations easily

Comment: Thanks  a lot Sir for the above query.How Can I normalize the same 3 tables and use the query you were talking about.It would be a great help if you can show me the same .Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks you rock.I have an additional query here.If in the above case I start typing "ne" or "new"(auto_suggestion) all fields have this text so in case of ambiguity how do I deal this problem? Sorry for the trouble but this  has been worrying me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jason its better to ask a new question with all the relevant details ,also provide me the link for new question here so i will also try to look at regards

Comment: Thanks will do that in sometime and post a link here.Thanks again for your time.