# MySQL :: Select from comma separated string

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following tables:

***filters***

```
id | u_ids
1  | 1, 2, 3
2  | 5, 6
```

*users*

```
id | name
1  | Tom
2  | Tim
3  | Sue
4  | Bruce
5  | Ann
6  | George
```

And I want to run the following select

```
select * from users where id in (select u_ids from filters where id =1);
```

I would like to receive

```
id | name
1  | Tom
2  | Tim
3  | Sue
```

But I receive nothing.

The problem is that the field `u_ids` is a text so the "in select" is returning something like "1, 2, 3" (with the semicolon) so the **in** does not find any value.

Is there any option to make a casting or something to change the string to an array?

Comment: How do you come to have a string in the first place instead of a normalized structure ?

Comment: Recently answered regarding above problem [*sql join tables where 1 column has comma*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma/25612053#25612053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to normalize your schema do not store relations in form of comma separated list instead create a junction table for this like to maintain a **m:m** many to many relation between users and filters,create a new table as `user_filters` with columns filter id and user id and in each row save one association per user and filter like in your current schema relation for filter 1 with many users `(1, '1, 2, 3')`  will become like

```
filter id user id
    (1, '1'),
    (1, '2'),
    (1, '3'),
```

---

Sample schema will be like this

```
CREATE TABLE user_filters
    (`fid` int, `u_id` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO user_filters
    (`fid`, `u_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '1'),
    (1, '2'),
    (1, '3'),
    (2, '5'),
    (2, '5')
;

CREATE TABLE filters
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO filters
    (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test'),
    (2, 'test 1')
;


CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom'),
    (2, 'Tim'),
    (3, 'Sue'),
    (4, 'Bruce'),
    (5, 'Ann'),
    (6, 'George')
;
```

For above schema you can easily query with join as, below query can be optimized using indexes

```
select u.* 
from users u
join user_filters uf on(uf.u_id = u.id)
 where uf.fid =1
```

### [Sample Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6583c9/1)

---

If you are not able to alter your schema and want to stick with the current one you can query as below but this one cannot be optimized enough as compare to above query

```
select u.* 
from users u
join filters f on(find_in_set(u.id,replace(`u_ids`,' ','')) > 0)
 where f.id =1
```

### [Sample Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b3af1/4)

### [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)