# Mysql/php search query with exact match

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

item_ids

```
id  | items
---------------------------
 1  | 12, 42, 71, 3
 2  | 64, 13, 52, 7, 1
 3  | 1, 5, 8, 10, 16
```

I will like to search for the record that has exact match as the user entered. for instance. if a user enters the number "7" the result be item with id "2" (64, 13, 52, 7, 1) and NOT item with id of "1" (12, 42, 71, 3) although it contains 7 in the "71".

Thank you.

I have already had a look of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644986/mysql-select-from-comma-separated-string/) and it is not the same as what I want.

the values of "Items"(numbers) are NOT for relational purpose, thanks.

Comment: What kind of records can the user search? Is it just one number or it can be something like `71,3`?

Comment: one number like 3 or 56. but NOT 3, 56.

Comment: @amdixon There is a reason I data structured this was in the database. it is not relational. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

SELECT id FROM item_ids WHERE items LIKE "% 7 %";

Comment: That won't work. if the items `string` is: `7,4,5`