# Select from two tables where left column IN content right column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

users:

```
+-------+-------------+------+
| id    | name        | type |
+-------+-------------+------+
|   1   | Name 1      |  1   |
|   2   | Name 2      |  2   |
|   3   | Name 3      |  3   |
+-------+-------------+------+
```

messages:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id    |  poster_id  |  message  | for_type |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1   |      3      |   mess1   |     1    |
|   2   |      2      |   mess2   |    2,3   |
|   3   |      1      |   mess3   |    3,1   |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

What query for get messages on **$user_type** in for_type ?

```
SELECT messages.*, users.name FROM messages LEFT JOIN users ON 
messages.poster_id = users.id WHERE messages.id > ' . $last_message_id . ' AND 
' . $user_type . ' IN (messages.for_type) 
ORDER BY news.id ASC
```

Comment: See normalization , its bad design. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644986/mysql-select-from-comma-separated-string/25645475#25645475

Comment: The current scheme is convenient for me. I updated post

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood right, you want to select a particular for_type and have the problem that the column is not correctly normalised, having more than one value. If you cannot normalise the structure correctly a LIKE command in the where clause would work, for example:

```
for_type LIKE "%1%"
```

Will get record 1 and 3 from messages.

Comment: It's works only on number less 10 :)

Comment: I'm think of changing type_num to type_name and using LIKE

Comment: Yep, using LIKE gives loads of potential solutions on that column. Give us an upvote if I have helped.