# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT field from second table using a relationship

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, find-in-set

Let's say we have a `tally_sheets` table which contains some tally sheets information like in the following description and a `persons` table described below with a `tally_sheets` field containing a list of tally sheet's IDs separated by comma.

Every tally sheet contain only peoples from a country/city combination.

How to get a list of all tally sheets with all fields from `tally_sheets` and `country` and `city` fields from `persons` table?

```
mysql> desc tally_sheets;
+-----------+--------------+
| Field     | Type         |
+-----------+--------------+
| id        | int(10)      |
| date      | char(10)     |
| person    | varchar(64)  |
| comment   | varchar(255) |
| timestamp | timestamp    |
+-----------+--------------+

mysql> desc persons;
+------------------+--------------+
| Field            | Type         |
+------------------+--------------+
| id               | int(11)      |
| name             | varchar(30)  |
| country          | varchar(60)  |
| city             | varchar(60)  |
| tally_sheets     | varchar(64)  | <== comma separated tally_sheet's ID
+------------------+--------------+
```

Running

```
SELECT ts.id, ts.date, p.country, p.city, ts.person, ts.`comment`, '0' AS sqlExclude 
FROM tally_sheets ts 
RIGHT JOIN persons p ON ts.id IN (p.tally_sheets) 
GROUP BY p.city
```

will give all country/city combinations but all the other fields are `NULL`.

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+
| id   | date | country    | city               | person | comment | sqlExclude |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+
| NULL | NULL | Country1   | City1              | NULL   | NULL    | 0          |
| NULL | NULL | Country1   | City2              | NULL   | NULL    | 0          |
| NULL | NULL | Country2   | City3              | NULL   | NULL    | 0          |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+
```

Running `SELECT ts.id, p.country, p.city FROM persons p LEFT JOIN tally_sheets ts ON ts.id IN (p.tally_sheets) GROUP BY p.city` will also return `NULL` fields.

```
+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | country    | city               |
+------+------------+--------------------+
| NULL | Country1   | City1              |
| NULL | Country1   | City2              |
| NULL | Country2   | City3              |
+------+------------+--------------------+
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Normalize your schema, don't use comma-separated lists.

Comment: @Barmar, I can't touch any table. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would say you should normalize your schema and read about [**`Database_normalization`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for handling relationships,If you are not able to alter your schema you can use `find_in_set`,Also `in()` will not work for comma separated list stored in your column

```
SELECT ts.id, ts.date, p.country, p.city, ts.person, ts.comment, '0' AS sqlExclude 
FROM tally_sheets ts 
RIGHT JOIN persons p ON find_in_set(ts.id ,p.tally_sheets) >0
```

Here is the [**reference answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma/25612053#25612053) how you can normalize your structure

Comment: Can't touch the tables structure. Your code works fine but it return a list of all persons. Adding `GROUP BY p.country, p.city` will return all tally sheets. Thank you!