# group_concat text field in mysql

Tags: mysql

Tried to group_concat a text field in mysql.But its taking only the first value.(if the values are '177,178') it taking only 177 because I am saving this as a text field.So how can I do group_concat with this fields?

My query looks as such:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(abc.displayValue SEPARATOR ' ') FROM abc WHERE abc.lookupId IN ('177,178')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you misplacing the quotes within your `IN`?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(abc.displayValue SEPARATOR ',') FROM abc WHERE abc.lookupId IN (177,178)
```

Comment: Why would a missing comma cause this problem?

Comment: Comma is the default separator, so I think he really wants to use space instead.

Comment: @Barmar yes you're right! It's not a must to have it though. +1 for pointing it out! I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with `GROUP_CONCAT`, the problem is that your `WHERE` clause is only selecting one row. Since the `lookupId` field is an integer, it's converting the string `'177,178'` to an integer, which is just `177`. You shouldn't have quotes around the values in the `IN()` list, that's making it just a single value to look for.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(abc.displayValue SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM abc 
WHERE abc.lookupId IN (177, 178)
```

If the comma-separated string is actually coming from a column in a table you're joining with, see [sql join tables where 1 column has comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma/25612053#25612053).

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table1.displayValue SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table1.lookupID, table2.lookupIDs)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Actually I am saving this lookupID as a varchar field since I have to store both 177,178 in a single row(may be I need to store more values in a single row such as 179,180 in future).So the table storing the values in the format '177,178'(like 'abc').Its taking this 177,178 as a single charcter.So how to group concatinate this?

Comment: You shouldn't store comma-separated values in a single field, you should use another table where each `lookupID` is in a different row. But if you're stuck with this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma/25612053#25612053.