# Mysql - Display Team name and Count of Team members from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

The following query works great

```
SELECT
          t.name, 
          t.id
        FROM
          team t,
          member m
        WHERE
          m.team_id = t.id
```

and shows multiple results
what I am stuck with it is with how to modify the query about to display the team name and the number of team members in that team so, for example, Team A has 50 team members, Team B has 20 members and so on.

The problem is that the `member.team_id` has Comma separated values

[image]

My table structure for `team` table

[image]

My table structure for `member` table

[image]

Not a duplicate question at all

Comment: Are you stuck with that table structure? I can't think of a use case for using comma-separated values in a database instead of a linking table.

Comment: @SolarBear not with the table structure but with the query, Unfortunately I cannot change the tables, so was wondering if the query can be modified to display the team name and the respective counts (team members)

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row

Comment: @SolarBear I tried GROUP BY t.name but how do I add the count to the query to display the right results

Comment: It's is not a great idea to store the team members as a comma separated list, and I also don't see how that query works. For example you are joining an integer to a varchar

Comment: Your original query won't work correctly, it will only match the first team in `member.team_id`. To make it work correctly, you need to use `FIND_IN_SET`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma/25612053#25612053

Comment: @Used_By_Already since team_id is stored as comma separated values it has to be varchar, I understand that its not the right way, but I do not have enough permission to change the table structure.

Comment: but what I am saying is that your query is NOT great. I don't even know how i works at all. Are you certain you query does not join using t.id = m.id ?

Comment: @Barmar I tried SELECT * 
FROM team t
JOIN member m ON ( FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30 it shows right records but how do I count those and display team name here?

Comment: `SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) FROM team t JOIN member m ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0 GROUP BY t.name`

Comment: That's the same way you would get the count if you were using a more normal way to join the tables.

Comment: @Barmar this works great, please post your answer and I will accept :)

Comment: @Barmar you should be able to post now 

SELECT t.name, COUNT( * ) 
FROM team t
JOIN member m ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0
GROUP BY t.name
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the technique in [sql join tables where 1 column has comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611999/sql-join-tables-where-1-column-has-comma?noredirect=1&lq=1) to join the tables, then use `COUNT(*)` to get the member counts.

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM team t 
JOIN member m 
ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) > 0 
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of members from comma separated list try using length() and replace()

```
select
(LENGTH(team_ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(team_ids, ',', '')))+1
from MyTable
```

By removing the commas the length is reduced by the number of those, and ou need 1 more because there isn't a trailing comma at the  end.

Comment: Not sure how this will be used in a join query, tried this but it does not give the intended results

 select t.name, 
          t.id
        FROM
          team t,
          member m
where 
(LENGTH(m.team_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(m.team_id, ',', '')))+1

Comment: it is NOT used in the where clause, use it is the select clause to display the number of team members, that is what you asked for isn't it?

Comment: @Used_By_Already This is backwards. This will return the number of teams that each member is on, not the number of members of each team.